# Getting Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3042:46) this error in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

Guyz getting this error i have added pdf.js file also and i'm upgrading node version that time i have got this error if anyone know please let me know

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js 3042:46
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3042:46)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |             key: "getJSActions",
  |             value: function getJSActions() {

> ```
>           return this._jsActionsPromise ||= this._transport.getPageJSActions(this._pageIndex);
> ```

|             }
|           }, {

Answer (score 0):

It's a compile error. Node said "you need an additional loader to handle this issue" which means while you update you node, something happens in one of your loader file. You should re-install "the issue loader" and then run it again. Are you building your app with CRA template? if so, you should re-install CRA template again and then move all files into the new project folder and run it.

I hope you find a solution! :D

Comment: ok I will Try it how to reinstall the loader but I'm trying to upgrade the version of my existing project.

Comment: Yes :D If my answer helped you, pls select my answer :D